# How to convert current string comparison (case sensitive) to case insensitive globally in a C# .NET framework Application

Tags: .net, string, string-comparison, .net-4.8

Is there something I can add in my configurations or define globally so that it will convert all the current case sensitive comparisons to case insensitive comparisons.

I can spend a day or two to go through the whole application and change every comparison but looking for an alternative.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want something so weird? "banana" isn't the same as "Banana". No application would require case insensitive equality everywhere. It's easy to perform case-insensitive comparisons in the few cases you really need it with eg [String.Equals(string,StringComparison)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.equals?view=net-6.0#system-string-equals(system-string-system-stringcomparison)) You can specify a Dictionary<string,T>` that uses a case-insensitive StringComparer, eg ` new Dictionary<string, int>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

Comment: Convert your all your strings to lower case with ```ToLower()``` function, and then compare the strings.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You have a problem X and assume Y is the solution. When that fails you ask about Y, not the actual problem X. What's the *actual* problem you want to solve?

Comment: @marco that's a very bad idea and extremely wasteful. Strings are immutable so every call to `ToLower()` creates a new string. It's not needed either, because it *is* possible to perform case-insensitive comparisions, use case-insensitive keys and dictionaries. The cost of allocating and garbage-collecting so many objects could easily cause 10x delays. At least

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you're right, sorry.